# QT gives error when I try to initialize QSerialPort outside the mainwindow.cpp

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to make an USB communication in QT. But when I write the codes:

```
#include "usb.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QtSerialPort>
#include <QSerialPortInfo>
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPortInfo>
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPortInfo>
#include <QSerialPort>


USB::USB()
{
    QSerialPort *serial;
    serial = new QSerialPort(this);
}
```

Inside of some source which is not my mainwindow.cpp. It gives me "no matching constructor for initialization of 'QSerialPort' " error. But when I try to initialize it in mainwindow.cpp, there are no errors. So I guess something missing in these sources.

How can I get rid of this error and open that serialPort in any other source but my mainwindow?

I am new to QT and also to C++, so probably that is an easy question, sorry about that beforehand.

Comment: What is `USB` class? `QSerialPort` object cannot be constructed out of an arbitrary class.

Comment: `QSerialPort` expects `QObject` as a parent and your `USB` class is not. Solution: Make `USB` subclass of `QObject`.

Comment: So I need to convert my USB class to a child class of my MainWindow class. Am I right? Is there a documentation about sub classes, parent and children classes around? Thanks.

Comment: Check the __Resources__ here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/qt/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare the USB class as follows:

```
class USB : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    USB() : serial(new QSerialPort(this)) {}

private:
    QSerialPort *serial;
};
```

Comment: That worked. But do I need to call this USB class in the main class? Or will it be called automatically? If yes, how can I call it from my main class?

Comment: This only *declares* a class. You will need to create an instance somewhere and keep a reference or pointer to it. Partial list of options: local variable inside `main`, field inside your `MainWindow` or other class, static field of some class (like MainWindow) or global variable.